# How to import tensorflow in python CGI program on CentOS server

Tags: python, apache, gcc, tensorflow, cgi

I can't import tensorflow in my python CGI program on my server.

I have a VPS with CentOS6.9 operation system. I already installed gcc-4.9.0 and python3.6 so I can run python script which import tensorflow and keras.

Now I want to write a python CGI program which also import tensorflow and keras. But as soon as I add "import tensorflow as tf" my script returns a server 500 error. After removing this line of code my script runs fine. The same situation goes for keras module as well.

I googled some. It seems to be related to apache enviroment values maybe it still use gcc-4.4.7 although I already linked usr/bin/gcc to my latest gcc-4.9.0. But there are not exlaborate answer to this.

The error log on apache shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.7' not found (required by /usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.7' not found (required by /usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I got this error before when running the script as python script through SSH. After updating gcc on my server and change the link under 'usr/bin/gcc' I already fix it when running as python script. But somehow the apache configuration still use the old gcc. So I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: And what is the error in the Apache error logs?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Sorry, just add the error log. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you installing tensorflow from a binary wheel. If so it was likely built against a newer C/C++ compiler version and the compiler on your system is too old. When you ``pip`` install it, use options to have ``pip`` ignore any binary wheel and compile it from source code on your system.